# Display URL in an Android app

Tags: android, android-studio, webview, textview

I am trying to display the content of an URL in my Android application instead of opening it in browser. Is there a way for that?

As in use WebView as well as TextView. An example image is here:

[image]

I need a way where TextView shall take care of my "grey"writings and WebView shall take care of my "green" URL link.

Comment: What is your issue with using both `WebView` and `TextView`?

Comment: Will it come in a single flow then..I guess no. Do advice.

Comment: Can I do something like enable WebView only when an URL appears, otherwise it will be `visible-gone` Maybe that will help.

Comment: Yes it can be done. Try something out and show the code if you have any issues,

Answer (score 0):

Use `textView.setText(Html.fromHtml(yourTextViewText));`

Comment: Thanks, but my URL is not generated by me but it comes from the DB at some certain places